# dplyr filter-brand new to R, how do I filter out multiple values from a single column

Tags: r

How can I filter out (exclude) from a single column called "record". I would like to **exclude** record = (1,2,3,6,8,10,15,16) from a single column. dataset name is "*sample*". Sorry for a simple question I am brand new to R.

[sample data set below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uK8AW.png)

Comment: `df %>% filter(!record %in% c(1,2,3,6,8,10,15, 16))`

Answer (score 0):

The dplyr library from tidyverse is very helpful for these types of problems.

```
library(dplyr)
df_filtered<-df %>%
    filter(!(record %in% c(1,2,3,6,8,10,15,16)))
```